# jQuery .find() inside .each() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, each

Currently I'm stuck in a very basic jQuery problem. I think there's something I do not understand about jquery's .each().

So this is my code:

```
     $('.test-list .test-item').each(() => {
        console.log($(this).find('.test-paragraph').text()); //not working always empty
     });
```

I'm just iterating over a bunch of items which perfectly works. But then I want to get the text of the.test-paragraph inside my element. The problem is that the find() method isn't working. Alle the html element exist.

```
<div class="test-list">
   <div class="test-item">
      <p class="test-paragraph">Test 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="test-item">
      <p class="test-paragraph">Test 2</p>
   </div>
   <div class="test-item">
      <p class="test-paragraph">Test 3</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: @PranavCBalan omg omg of course! THX very much! I need definitely more sleep.

Comment: `$('.test-list .test-item .test-paragraph').text((i, txt) => console.log(txt))` https://jsfiddle.net/53Lm73fu/

Comment: Or just use its parameter, which is more in keeping with standard APIs anyway. `$('.test-list .test-item').each((i, el) => { console.log($(el).find('.test-paragraph').text()); });` https://jsfiddle.net/53Lm73fu/1/ While this is closer to standard iteration methods, jQuery decided to reverse the params. If you were using `.forEach` instead, the `el` would be the first param.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and ***does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target***. Arrow functions are always anonymous. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Inside of arrow function `this` won't refers to the element, so instead use the normal function.

```
$('.test-list .test-item').each(function() {
   console.log($(this).find('.test-paragraph').text());
});
```

---

Or you can use [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text) method with a callback to iterate and get text content of the element.

```
$('.test-list .test-item .test-paragraph').text((i, text) => console.log(text))
```

---

Or instead of `this` use the second argument in the arrow function and as per the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function) which refer to the element.

```
$('.test-list .test-item').each((i, ele) => console.log($(ele).find('.test-paragraph').text()));
```